# javascript: pass / accept params to func

Tags: javascript, arguments, parameter-passing

I have generic function at javasciprt.
It accept : other func to call, and params to send.
It looks like:

```
    function generic(func, funcArguments){
       //my Code...
       func(funcArguments);
    }
```

suppose I call generic func from func called myFunc:

```
   function myFunc(a, b){
        generic(foo, arguments);//argument will pass a and b, as js rules
   }


   function foo(a, b){
       ///my code
   }
```

The result is that foo function all of the argument as one entity that pass to parameter a.

it not good for me.
I need it to accept a into a and b into b.
But I cannot send them simply, becouse each time I accept differance count of params.

Is there any way to implement this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to call the method will `apply(context, arguments)`. Then the arguments will be provided as separate members of the arguments array, instead of just one argument.

```
function generic(func, funcArguments){
   func.apply(this, funcArguments);
}
```

Comment: is it quickly efficient Performance like regular call function? i.e., is it more "heavy" than simple function calling? and about the passing- is there way to pass the parameters separtedly, too? it important for cases when I don't want to pas all arguments

Comment: Although this is out of scope for your question "Is there any way to implement this logic?", apply and call do not affect performance and if you want to modify the arguments before passing them you can.

Comment: "you can"- but how? suppose func 'my func' get 3 arguments a, b, c and I want to pass to func 'generic' only argument a, c- how can I do it?

Comment: newarguments = [];
newarguments.push(arguments[0]);
newarguments.push(arguments[2]);
func.apply(this, newarguments);

Comment: You're welcome. Another way would be to do arguments = arguments.splice(1, 1);